# emplace_back and shared_ptr vector in VS2012

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, stl, shared-ptr

I have the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

struct monkey
{
    int mA, mB;

    monkey(int a, int b) : mA(a), mB(b)
    {
    }
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<std::vector<monkey>> MonkeyContainer;


int main()
{
    MonkeyContainer monkeyContainer;
    monkeyContainer->emplace_back(1, 2);
}
```

And it always crashes on `emplace_back()`. Yet it compiles fine, and I can't see any problem. Why does it crash?
Here is the exception thrown and the code line:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00FE2299 in ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008.
```

at

```
vector.h - line 894: _VARIADIC_EXPAND_0X(_VECTOR_EMPLACE, , , , )
```

I am using VS2012 and have tried both with the November CTP and the default compiler.

I cannot use VS2013 atm because of lack of boost support and other factors - is there a fix for MSVC11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `vector<monkey>` that will be managed by the `shared_ptr`.

```
MonkeyContainer monkeyContainer;
```

After the above statement the `shared_ptr` points to `nullptr` (`monkeyContainer.get() == nullptr`), and deferencing it to call `emplace_back` results in the crash. Change the above line to

```
MonkeyContainer monkeyContainer = std::make_shared<std::vector<monkey>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't initializing your `MonkeyContainer` pointer. It's pointing to `NULL` when you try to `emplace_back`.